# Using ajax to post a form to php without refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I have this written up for send a few variables to a php script:

```
$(function() {

$('a[class="removeUnread"]').click(function(){

   var markedtopicid = $(this).attr("id");
   var sessionvar     = \'', $context['session_var'], '\';
   var sessionid = \'', $context['session_id'], '\';


   $.ajax({
      url: "index.php?action=quickmod;board=', $context['current_board'], '", 
      type: "POST",
      data: sessionvar + "=" + sessionid + "&topics[]=" + markedtopicid + "&qaction=markread",
    });

});
```

});

I think this is the correct way to send post data via ajax, but it doesn't appear to be sending. Was I right to wrap the code in the ready function?

Comment: url: "index.php?action=quickmod;board=', $context['current_board'], '" - is that supposed to be php code? if so, it should be in <?php echo $context['current_board']; ?>

Comment: It's within a php template, and it's contained within a function that loads in the header.

Comment: You have to add PHP tags when you are using PHP code in Javascript
<?=$context['current_board']?>

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you right off the bat you should not have a semicolon between quickmod and board in your URL. I'm answering here because i cannot post comments yet. One good tool to use in web development ESPECIALLY with GET and POST requests is googles PostMan app. Its free to use and what it does is it will show you the exact output of any link you send it. So you can try putting the link that you make via javascript into postman and see what errors it spits out.

In this example i'm pretty sure your URL is all kinds of screwed up though. Try this instead...

```
"index.php?action=quickmod&?board="+$context['current_board']
```

fyi, i did not test that link so it may not work. If it doesnt work, google some ajax examples and javascript string concatenation. You're string is not suitable for ajax.

Comment: You have an extra question mark after the ampersand.

Comment: Adjusted the extra ? and this unfortunately didn't work either. Basically, I need in the POST body to supply:
* the session variable pointing to the session id,
* qaction=markread
* topics[] = topic id

Answer (score 1):

is should be like this...

```
$.ajax({
                url :'index.php',
                type : 'POST',
                data : { sessionvar: sessionid, topics:markedtopicid}, 
                success : function (data) {

                        },
                error : function () {

                        }
```

Comment: data will have all data items you wanna to POST, or you can use var sData = jQuery("#form_id").serializeArray(); as data:sData to directly serialize the all form data for ajax POST

Answer (score 0):

Try handling the error:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "index.php?action=quickmod;board=', $context['current_board'], '", 
      type: "POST",
      data: sessionvar + "=" + sessionid + "&topics[]=" + markedtopicid + "&qaction=markread",
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {                
         alert(xhr.responseText);
     }
});
```

Comment: I attempted this, but it's not actually giving me an error, even though it still sin't working, unfortunately.